# Configuring spring-xd to use oracle as job repository

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I want to run spring xd with Oracle(11g) which i already have in my environment. Currently my first concern is the jobs UI (my database has existing data of job executions that were performed by spring-batch and i simply want to display the details of those executions).

i'm using `spring-xd-1.0.0.M5`. I followed the [instructions in the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#_batch_jobs_accessing_jdbc) and i changed `application.yml` to have the following:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:oci:MY_USERNAME/MYPWD@//orarmydomain.com:1521/myservice
    username: MY_USERNAME
    password: MYPWD
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  profiles:
    active: default,oracle
```

i modified also `batch-jdbc.properties` to have the database configuration similar to the above.

Yet, when i start `xd-singlnode.bat` (or either `xd-admin.bat`) it seems like it ignores my oracle configuration and still uses the default *hsqldb*.
what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The likely reason is that we did not upgrade the windows .bat scripts to take advantage of the property overriding via xd-config.yml.  If you go into the unix script for xd-singlenode you will see that when java is invoked there there is an option

-Dspring.config.location=$XD_CONFIG

you can for now hardcode your location of that file, use file: as the prefix.

Also, The UI right now is very primitive, you will not be able to see many details about the job execution.  There are however many job related commands you can execute in the shell and there is only one gap regarding step execution information as compared to what is available via spring-batch-admin.

The issue to watch for this is https://jira.springsource.org/browse/XD-1209 and it is schedule for the next milestone release.

Let me know how it goes, thanks!

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yet, i'm still having the same problem. i added `-Dspring.config.location=file://%XD_HOME%/config/my-oracle-xd-config.yml` and it still seems to ignore my configuration